# fmincon in R - disappeared from 'pracma' package?

Tags: r, optimization

In the ['pracma' package manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/pracma.pdf) there is function **fmincon** to Minimize Nonlinear Constrained Multivariable Function (page 116). However I've installed this package, but there is no such function.

Has it been removed from this package?
Could anyone indicate any other R ackage or function with such funcionality (Minimize Nonlinear Constrained Multivariable Function) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of `pracma` do you have installed?  The manual you linked to is from version 2.2.5, and that's also the version on CRAN, and it *does* have `fmincon`.
Perhaps you forgot

```
library(pracma)
```

to attach it?  Installing isn't enough to make the contents visible.

Comment: I've installed version 2.0.7. That's the case :)